# When does a advancedDataGrid know when to display ScrollBar if it's configured with horizontalScrollbarPolicy = "auto"

Tags: apache-flex

I have a mx AdvancedDataGrid with horizontalScrollPolicy="auto". 
When does the advancedDataGrid know that it should display the ScrollBar?

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="periodGrid" styleName="Panel" sortExpertMode="true" selectionMode="singleCell"  dataProvider="{myPresenter.periodList}" width="100%" height="100%" sortableColumns="false" dragEnabled="false" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0">
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

But everytime I populate the periodList ( which cause the width of periodGrid Changed) it still does not show the scrollbar, and the datagrid is overflowing the container.

PS : after I Changed the periodList, I have put periodList.invalidateSize() also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by implementing updateDisplayList on the wrapper component.

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
                periodGrid.width = unscaledWidth - 10;
                periodGrid.height = unscaledHeight - 10;
            }
```